# Imprimir variables por línea más legible

Tags: python, python-2.7, print

Quiero crear una función que pueda imprimir variables por cada línea como ya tengo hecho, pero de una forma más legible.

```
    date_from = '2018-01-08 00:00:00'
    date_to = '2018-01-08 23:59:59'
    parent_cat = [14,23,51]
    f_categ_id = [24,23,32]
    previous = True
    previous = '_pre' if previous == True else ''
    print("SELECT \n" \
              "sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,\n" \
              "sum(l.qty * (l.price_unit - (l.discount * l.price_unit / 100)))::double precision AS price_total%s, \n" \
              "sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price%s, \n" \
              "sum(l.margin) as margin, \n" \
              "c.parent_id as parent_id, \n" \
              "t.categ_id as categ_id \n" \
          "FROM sale_order_line l \n" \
              "JOIN sale_order s on (l.order_id=s.id) \n" \
              "LEFT JOIN product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id) \n" \
              "LEFT JOIN product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id) \n" \
              "LEFT JOIN product_category c on (c.id=t.categ_id) \n" \
              "LEFT JOIN product_uom u on (u.id=l.product_uom) \n" \
              "LEFT JOIN product_uom u2 on (u2.id=t.uom_id) \n" \
          "WHERE \n" \
              "s.date_order >=%s and s.date_order <=%s and t.categ_id in %s and t.categ_id in %s \n"
          "GROUP BY \n" \
              "t.categ_id ,  c.parent_id" %(previous, previous, date_from, date_to, tuple(parent_cat), tuple(f_categ_id)))
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible quitar la parte de

```
%(previous, previous, date_from, date_to, tuple(parent_cat),
tuple(f_categ_id))
```

e ir añadiendo cada una de las variables en la línea que corresponda, por ejemplo algo como:

```
"sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price%s, \n" \ % previous
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No sé bien que estás queriendo hacer, pero armar una consulta SQL de esa forma puede hacer tu código vulnerable a inyección SQL. Si no sabés que es inyección SQL te sugiero que estudies un poco el tema antes de llevar eso a producción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de mejorar la legibilidad.

En python, se puede componer una cadena en varias líneas y combinar con variables (que sería lo que quieres):

```
"SELECT \n" \
   "sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,\n" \
   "sum(l.qty * (l.price_unit - (l.discount * l.price_unit / 100)))::double precision AS price_total%s, \n" \
   "sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price%s, \n" % previus\
...
```

Nota que he añadido `previus` al final.

Se puede hacer mejor si agrupamos las líneas con paréntesis, con lo que nos olvidamos del tener que añadir un `\` al final:

```
("SELECT \n"
   "sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,\n"
   "sum(l.qty * (l.price_unit - (l.discount * l.price_unit / 100)))::double precision AS price_total%s, \n"
   "sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price%s, \n" % previus
...
)
```

Pero es más elegante que usar literales multilínea:

```
"""\
SELECT 
    sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,
    sum(l.qty * (l.price_unit - (l.discount * l.price_unit / 100)))::double precision AS price_total%s, 
    sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price%s, 
    sum(l.margin) as margin, 
    c.parent_id as parent_id, 
    t.categ_id as categ_id 
FROM sale_order_line l 
    JOIN sale_order s on (l.order_id=s.id) 
    LEFT JOIN product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id) 
    LEFT JOIN product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id) 
    LEFT JOIN product_category c on (c.id=t.categ_id) 
    LEFT JOIN product_uom u on (u.id=l.product_uom) 
    LEFT JOIN product_uom u2 on (u2.id=t.uom_id) 
WHERE 
    s.date_order >=%s and s.date_order <=%s and t.categ_id in %s and t.categ_id in %s
GROUP BY 
    t.categ_id ,  c.parent_id
"""
```

Para darle valores a las variables, emplea el método `.format()` en lugar del operador `%` y asígnalas por nombre, algo así:

```
templ = """\
    SELECT 
        sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,
        sum(l.qty * (l.price_unit - (l.discount * l.price_unit / 100)))::double precision AS price_total{previous}, 
        sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.purchase_price ) as cost_price{previous}, 
        sum(l.margin) as margin, 
        c.parent_id as parent_id, 
        t.categ_id as categ_id 
    FROM sale_order_line l 
        JOIN sale_order s on (l.order_id=s.id) 
        LEFT JOIN product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id) 
        LEFT JOIN product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id) 
        LEFT JOIN product_category c on (c.id=t.categ_id) 
        LEFT JOIN product_uom u on (u.id=l.product_uom) 
        LEFT JOIN product_uom u2 on (u2.id=t.uom_id) 
    WHERE 
        s.date_order >= {date_from} and s.date_order <= {date_to} and t.categ_id in {parent_cat} and t.categ_id in {categs}
    GROUP BY 
        t.categ_id ,  c.parent_id
    """

query = templ.format(
    previous=previous,
    date_from=date_from,
    date_to=date_to,
    parent_cat=tuple(parent_cat),
    categs=tuple(f_categ_id)
)
```

Comment: La respuesta es perfecta. Muy bien explicado y con varios ejemplo. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.